# is suitable setting DTO into DAO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, dao, dto

I want to build a join query with 3 tables and I want to implement one only object to transfer around 6 fields from persistance layer to presentation layer. Is suitable creating one single DTO and set it into DAO ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it depends on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@JsonView](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) annotation.

It allows use one DTO in different situations(endpoints etc.)